# how to read gradlew runtime property as variable

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, parameters, properties

I need to take host value at Gradle build as below command.

```
./Gradlew build -Phost="HTTP://hostvalue"
```

I add the below code in `build.gradle` which is working correctly.

```
task takehost{
    if(project.hasProperty("host")){
        println("host is given at runtime")
        println(host)
    }
}
```

I need to import this host value to another file for comparison so if host value is given at build time then it will take this value otherwise it will take hardcoded file value.

can anyone let me know how to import this value into another file for the if-else condition?

Comment: Could you please be more specific what you mean by "import in another file"? Do you want to generate some code/resource file? Or are you talking about other parts of the build (e.g. other gradle files or plugins)?

Comment: I have another file static.groovy.in static.groovy file i have value for the host. my main purpose is that if value of host is provided at build time then it will take this value otherwise it will take host value from static.groovy. is there any simple way to take project parameter please let me know that would be wonderful

Comment: And when does static.groovy run? Is it part of the build or do you want to add this setting somewhere and when it later runs it uses the build time setting?

Comment: it is not part of the build. static.groovy file has a function which is called when other test cases need a host. so I need to take this value host to static.groovy file as a variable. and compares with my logic and run my testcase against correct host.

Comment: Then you need to generate a property file with the host value in your build and read that during your test run.